# Bash: text formatting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my shell script, I want to log status messages with text alignment. for example

```
STATUS 1          [OK]
STATUS 2      [FAILED]
PROCESS           [OK]
```

I tried `echo -e` with `\t` option, but I have to manually format the alignment

[EDIT]

This is the part I want text alignment

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo -e "[$(date +%F_%T)] Alter table $DB.$table\t\t\t\t\t\t[OK]">>$log
        sleep 1
else
        echo -e "[$(date +%F_%T)] Alter table $DB.$table\t\t\t\t\t\t[FAIL]">>$log
        exit
fi
```

**[SOLUTION]**

Found a solution thanks to @Jayesh and @evading

Created `writeLog` function

```
function writeLog(){
    printf "%s %`expr 100 - ${#1}`s\n" "$1" "$2">>$log
}
```

Call the function like this

writeLog "STATUS1" "OK"

Comment: Show us your script so that we could help you fix it.

Comment: @devnull I edited the question with a part of my script

Comment: use printf like `printf "%-20s %-10s" "status 1" "[OK]"`.

Comment: @Jayesh Line brake is missing

Comment: @userv yes it should be there.

Comment: @Jayesh can you please explain the printf statement

Comment: @userv I am not able to explain whole thing here but look some links like http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf and http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html. It will help you lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf "%-`expr 40 - ${#b}`s %-40s\n", $a, $b
```

Where a and b are variables and `expr 40 - ${#b}` does 40-length(b).

Comment: works perfect without ",". It should be `printf "%-`expr 40 - ${#b}`s %-40s\n" $a $b` Thank you

Comment: when length is 100 it gives me a weird output

Comment: @userv how wide is your terminal